# WITH Clause performance issue in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization, database-performance

Table myfirst3 have 4 columns and 1.2 million records.

Table mtl_object_genealogy has over 10 million records.

Running the below code takes very long time. How to tune this code using with options?

```
WITH level1 as ( 
    SELECT  mln_parent.lot_number, 
            mln_parent.inventory_item_id,
            gen.lot_num ,--fg_lot, 
            gen.segment1,
            gen.rcv_date.
    FROM mtl_lot_numbers mln_parent,
          (SELECT   MOG1.parent_object_id,
                    p.segment1,
                    p.lot_num,
                    p.rcv_date
            FROM mtl_object_genealogy MOG1 ,
                 myfirst3 p
            START WITH MOG1.object_id = p.gen_object_id
            AND (MOG1.end_date_active IS NULL OR MOG1.end_date_active > SYSDATE)
            CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR MOG1.parent_object_id = MOG1.object_id
            AND (MOG1.end_date_active IS NULL  OR MOG1.end_date_active > SYSDATE)
            UNION all
            SELECT p1.gen_object_id,
                   p1.segment1,
                   p1.lot_num,
                   p1.rcv_date 
            FROM myfirst3 p1 ) gen
    WHERE mln_parent.gen_object_id = gen.parent_object_id )
select /*+ NO_CPU_COSTING */ * 
from level1;
```

execution plan

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE APPS.MYFIRST3
(
  TO_ORGANIZATION_ID    NUMBER,
  LOT_NUM               VARCHAR2(80 BYTE),
  ITEM_ID               NUMBER,
  FROM_ORGANIZATION_ID  NUMBER,
  GEN_OBJECT_ID         NUMBER,
  SEGMENT1              VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  RCV_DATE              DATE
);

CREATE TABLE INV.MTL_OBJECT_GENEALOGY
(
  OBJECT_ID               NUMBER                NOT NULL,
  OBJECT_TYPE             NUMBER                NOT NULL,
  PARENT_OBJECT_ID        NUMBER                NOT NULL,
   START_DATE_ACTIVE       DATE                  NOT NULL,
  END_DATE_ACTIVE         DATE,
  GENEALOGY_ORIGIN        NUMBER,
  ORIGIN_TXN_ID           NUMBER,
  GENEALOGY_TYPE          NUMBER,
  );

CREATE INDEX INV.MTL_OBJECT_GENEALOGY_N1 ON INV.MTL_OBJECT_GENEALOGY(OBJECT_ID);

CREATE INDEX INV.MTL_OBJECT_GENEALOGY_N2 ON INV.MTL_OBJECT_GENEALOGY(PARENT_OBJECT_ID);
```

Comment: Where are the tables definition ? Execution plan? Please edit your question and provide all necessary information.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your explain plan shows some very big numbers. The optimizer reckons the final result set will be about 3227,000,000,000 rows. Just returning that many rows will take some time.

All table accesses are Full Table Scans. As you have big tables that will eat time too.

As for improvements, it's pretty hard to for us understand the logic of your query. This is your data model, you business rules, your data. You haven't explained anything so all we can do is guess.

Why are you using the WITH clause? You only use the `level` result set once, so just have a regular FROM clause.

Why are you using UNION ALL? That operation just duplicates the records retrieved from `myfirst3` ( all those values are already included as rows where `MOG1.object_id = p.gen_object_id`.

The MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN operation is interesting. Oracle uses it to implement transitive closure. It is an expensive operation but that's because treewalking a hierarchy is an expensive thing to do. It is unfortunate for you that you are generating all the parent-child relationships for a table with 27 million records. That's bad.

The full table scans aren't the problem. There are no filters on `myfirst3` so obviously the database has to get all the records. If there is one parent for each `myfirst3` record that's 10% of the contents `mtl_object_genealogy` so a full table scan would be efficient; but you're rolling up the entire hierarchy so it's like you're looking at a much greater chunk of the table.

Your indexes are irrelevant in the face of such numbers. What might help is a composite index on `mtl_object_genealogy(OBJECT_ID, PARENT_OBJECT_ID, END_DATE_ACTIVE)`.

You want all the levels of PARENT_OBJECT_ID for the records in `myfirst3`. If you run this query often and `mtl_object_genealogy` is a slowly changing table you should consider materializing the transitive closure into a table which just has records for all the permutations of leaf records and parents.

To sum up:

1. Ditch the WITH clause
2. Drop the UNION ALL
3. Tune the tree-walk with a composite index (or materializing it)